# Java Servlet File download dialog not showing

Tags: jquery, ajax, jsp, servlets, download

I have a web application which let user download a image file from the server. When user hit a button on jsp page a ajax post request is made which executes a servlet and in response sends a image file. But the issue is that image file never downloads and Save As dialog box is not coming up.

In the Firebug I can see that request is send correctly and response was received with the correct Contect Type and status code 200. I can also see binary data in the firebug Response tab but still for some reason image is not downloading. Pls help.

**Request:**
*Request URL:`http://localhost:8080/SVGToImage/convertToImg`

Request Method:POST

Status Code:200 OK*

**Response:**

*Content-Disposition:filename="out.jpg"

Content-Type:image/jpeg

Date:Fri, 31 May 2013 17:28:26 GMT

Server:Apache-Coyote/1.1

Transfer-Encoding:chunked*

**Here is my JSP**

```
<head>

<script>

    function exportToImage(){

    var svg = document.getElementById("ext-gen1040");       

    var svg1 = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(svg);

        jQuery.noConflict();

        jQuery.ajax({
            url: "convertToImg" ,
            type: "POST",
                    data: { q = svg1},
            success: function(data) {               
            },
          error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
              alert('Error ' + textStatus);
          }     
});

</script>

</head>

<body>
<input type="button" value="export" onclick="javascript:exportToImage();">
</body>
```

**On server side here is the servlet code:**

```
private void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response)  throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    String filePath = "C:/Users/nandan.jain/Pictures/out.jpg";
    File file = new File(filePath);
    int length   = 0;
    ServletOutputStream outStream = response.getOutputStream();

    response.setContentType("image/jpeg");
    response.setContentLength((int)file.length());
    String fileName = (new File(filePath)).getName();

    // sets HTTP header
    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + fileName + "\"");

    byte[] byteBuffer = new byte[BUFSIZE];
    DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));

    // reads the file's bytes and writes them to the response stream
    while ((in != null) && ((length = in.read(byteBuffer)) != -1))
    {
        outStream.write(byteBuffer,0,length);
    }

    in.close();
    outStream.close();


}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't download files with ajax. Ajax is executed by JavaScript language. The JavaScript language has for obvious security reasons no facilities to programmatically trigger a *Save As* dialog and provide arbitrary file content.

Just download it by a non-ajax request. If `Content-Disposition` header is set to `attachment`, the current page will remain unchanged anyway.

So, instead of that whole `jQuery.ajax()` thing, you could just do

```
window.location = "convertToImg?q=" + encodeURIComponent(svg1);
```

and perform the job in servlet's `doGet()` instead.

Or, if you really need POST, then make it a normal submit form.

```
<form action="convertToImg" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="svg1" />
    <input type="submit" onclick="exportToImage(this)" />
</form>
```

with

```
function exportToImage(button) {
    var svg = document.getElementById("ext-gen1040");       
    var svg1 = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(svg);
    button.form.svg1.value = svg1;
}
```

Please note that the concrete problem is completely unrelated to JSP/Servlets.

Comment: Hi BalusC, Thanks for the explanation. I made changes as per your suggestions and it worked fine. Thanks for helping me out and very quick response.

Comment: @BalusC I realize this post is from last year,  but it helped me to learn that you can't download files with ajax.  So I have a form that is submitted to a servlet (not via ajax) that creates a file and sends it to the browser for the user to download.  I want to show a loading image while this servlet is working though, because it takes a long time.  How can I show a loading image during this servlet processing if I am not using ajax to submit the form?